Errors in the implementation of the filter
enter image description here
How to fix the error in the image
I asked artificial intelligence but it could not help me.
C:\Users\Pentium>flutter doctor
Building flutter tool...
Running pub upgrade...
Resolving dependencies... (5.9s)
Because flutter_tools depends on test any which doesn't exist 
(authorization failed), version solving failed.

Insufficient permissions to the resource at the https://pub.dev 
package repository.
You can modify credentials using:
dart pub token add https://pub.dev
Error (69): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five 
seconds... (9 tries left)

Waiting for 0 seconds, press CTRL+C to quit ...


Hello and welcome! Did you try to do what the error message tells you to do?

hello
Yes, I did what he asked, but it says I need a token from the pub.dev site
I checked the pub.dev site but there is no such thing

Try update version build tool, ../build.gradle file like this:
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0'

And please use this commands before run project:
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter upgrade

